# Obtain MIN() and MAX() over not correlative values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem that I can't found a solution. This is my scenario:

```
parent_id | transaction_code | way_to_pay | type_of_receipt | unit_price | period | series | number_from | number_to | total_numbers
10        | 2444             |  cash      |   local         | 15.000     |  2018  |   A    |   19988     |    26010  | 10
```

This result's when a grouping `parent_id, transaccion_code, way_to_pay, type_of_receipt, unit_price, periodo, series, MIN(number), MAX(number) and COUNT(number)`. But the grouping hides that the **number** is not correlative, because this is my childs situation:

```
parent_id | child_id | number 
10        |   1      | 19988 
10        |   2      | 19989
10        |   3      | 19990
10        |   4      | 19991
10        |   5      | 22001
10        |   6      | 22002
10        |   7      | 26007
10        |   8      | 26008
10        |   9      | 26009
10        |   10     | 26010
```

What is the magic SQL to achieve the following?

```
parent_id | transaction_code | way_to_pay | type_of_receipt | unit_price | period | series | number_from | number_to | total_numbers
10        | 2444             |  cash      |   local         | 15.000     |  2018  |   A    |   19988     |    19991  | 4
10        | 2444             |  cash      |   local         | 15.000     |  2018  |   A    |   22001     |    22002  | 2
10        | 2444             |  cash      |   local         | 15.000     |  2018  |   A    |   26007     |    26010  | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify adjacent numbers by subtracting a sequence.  It would help if you showed your query, but the idea is this:

```
select parent_id, transaccion_code, way_to_pay, type_of_receipt, unit_price, periodo, series,
       min(number), max(number), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over
                 (partition by parent_id, transaccion_code, way_to_pay, type_of_receipt, unit_price, periodo, series
                  order by number
                 ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by parent_id, transaccion_code, way_to_pay, type_of_receipt, unit_price, periodo, series,
         (number - seqnum);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Your post help me!